# Simple router with URL parameter variables

Tags: javascript, url, single-page-application, url-parameters

I'm trying to make a simple router with URL parameters for IDs. e.g. `localhost/profile/123` This works fine but if I remove `preventDefault` so that the links work as normal, or refresh the browser, or go directly to that same URL,  it does not work and the browser looks for the javascript file `main.js` in `localhost/profile` instead of the origin `localhost`. Routes without parameters work fine. What is happening here?

```
const router = async path => {

  if(!path) path = location.pathname

  const segment = route.split('/')

  path =  '/' + segment[1]
  const parameter = segment[2]

  const routes = {
    '/' : { handler: home },
    '/about' : { handler: about },
    '/profile' : { handler: profile },
  }

  render(html`
    <main>${await routes[path].handler(parameter ? parameter : '')}</main>
  `, document.body)
}



const main = async () => {

    await router()

    document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {

      e.preventDefault()

      if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
        let path = e.target.pathname

        history.pushState({urlPath: path}, '', location.origin + path)
        onpopstate = () => router()

        router(path)
      }

    })
}

main()
```

Comment: You need server-side URL rewriting to handle direct loading of URLs. As for loading `main.js` from the wrong path, you need to use absolute paths when referencing assets, eg `<script src="/main.js">` instead of `<script src="main.js">`

Comment: Duplicate of [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually) / [Vue Router return 404 when revisit to the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399319/vue-router-return-404-when-revisit-to-the-url) / etc. This problem comes up all the time for anything that uses history push-state routing

Comment: Ok thanks! Since this is a duplicate I'll delete it.