# Vue app deployed on Azure app service gives "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a Vue 2.0 app, no server side rendering. What I deploy to Azure App Service, I just upload the content of "dist" folder to "wwwroot" folder using FTP.

The home page loads fine, when I navigate through the pages using links, all pages loads fine. But when I hit refresh or go to a route directly by pasting the url into the address bar and hit enter. I got the following error:

```
 The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I use vue-router and webpack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue Router return 404 when revisit to the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399319/vue-router-return-404-when-revisit-to-the-url)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45777994/192727 This was solved by the linked answer above