# 404 Error after successful authentication with Passport.js unless redirected to '/'

Tags: express, vue.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have an Express server on the backend that uses Passport.js for authentication. Even when successfully authenticated, a 404 error is shown in the webbrowser, when redirecting to '/about', '/login', or any other path (all those paths exists on the frontend), or even when not redirecting. **The only time a 404 is not shown is if a redirect to '/' is made.** I will include the relevant code snippets below.

**users.js**

```
router.post('/api/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      // res.statusCode is still 200 here!!!!!!!!
      return res.redirect('/about');
    });
  })(req, res, next);
})
```

***Alternative* users.js** (has same issue)

```
router.post('/api/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/about',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' }))
```

**passportLocalStrategy.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const init = require('./passportSessionConfig');
const knex = require('../db/connection');
const authUtils = require('./utils')

init();

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
},
function (username, password, done) {
  // check to see if the username exists
  knex('users')
  .where({ 'email': username })
  .orWhere({ username })
  .first()
  .then((results) => {
    if (!results) return done(null, false);
    if (!authUtils.comparePass(password, results.password)) {
      return done(null, false);
    } else return done(null, results);
  })
  .catch((err) => { return done(err); });
}));

module.exports = passport;
```

This is the frontend javascript code that made the request (Vue.js)

```
methods: {
  login: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password,
      returnTo: window.location.pathname
    };
    this.axios
      .post("/api/login", data)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("Logged in");
        this.$router.push("/about");
      })
      .catch(errors => {
        console.log("Cannot log in");
        console.log(errors);
      });
  }
}
```

**This is the 404 error from the webbrowser**
[image: This is the 404 error from the webbrowser]

Comment: Sounds like this issue ~ [Vue Router return 404 when revisit to the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399319/vue-router-return-404-when-revisit-to-the-url). See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: Also, I don't think you should be returning a _redirect_ response from an API call. Your backend is trying to redirect to `/about` but your frontend is then trying to go to `/dashboard`. Just return a success or failure response status from your API

Comment: @Phil I meant to have /about not /dashboard, but either way it never hits the `then` function because of the status 404. It instead goes to the `catch`.

Comment: Like I said, don't respond with a redirect from your API calls. Let the frontend handle the routing and navigation