# Redirected from "/" to "/" via a navigation guard. AND Refresh Page 404

Tags: vue.js

i have this problem.. Please help me. What is navigation guard?

[image]

And, I'm complate my project and update Windows Server. Website running and if i click reflesh, go to 404 Page..

```
First: 200
Reflesh: 404
```

Comment: [Vue Router - Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue Router return 404 when revisit to the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399319/vue-router-return-404-when-revisit-to-the-url)

Comment: Phil, thanks my fixed 404 problem.