# Vue Router Hard Realod Problem (404 Not Found)

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I’m fetching a problem when I refresh or hard reload the site it shows 4O4 Not Found.

Stack:
Frontend - VueJs(v3), Vue-Router(v4), Tailwindcss(v3)
Backend - Laravel(v8)
Server: Nginx

I’ve tried more and more but not working.
Link:

1. [Vue Router return 404 when revisit to the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399319/vue-router-return-404-when-revisit-to-the-url)
2. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#apache

First tried:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

When not working then used:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]

    # Disable index view
    Options -Indexes

    # Hide a specific file
    <Files .env>
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    </Files>
</IfModule>
```

I can’t understand what should do. Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: You are using nginX but `mod_rewrite` is for Apache - don't try to use it with nginX!

Comment: thanks. But have any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Where did you paste `location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}` ?

Comment: `location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}` used in **.htaccess** file

Comment: This syntax is for nginX - not for Apache. If you're using nginX (which you did state in the question above) - you must put this into the corresponding `server` block in `nginx.conf`. nginX does not use and does not recognize `.htaccess` files.