# Vue-router not finding direct routes when deployed in Netlify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, html5-history

I have deployed an app in Netlify, the link is: https://www.fluento.net. The website is working correctly, but whenever I try to access for example https://www.fluento.net/start, I get 404 error. If I go to the root url and press on the Start button, I get correctly redirected to https://www.fluento.net/start.

I have searched online and saw it might be a problem with **history mode** but I can't seem to figure out how to solve the issue.

This is the configuration of the router:

```
const routes = [
  //Some routes in here, 404 not set!
]

const router = createRouter({                                                                         
  history: createWebHistory(),                                                                        
  routes                                                                                              
})
```

I have seen some solutions to add some configuration to nginx and so on, but my app is deployed in Netlify automatically when pushing to github, so I do not have any nginx configuration file or anything.

Also, I have seen that adding a catch all route and redirecting to index could work (as explained in the [vue docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-mode)), but it didn't work for me, or maybe I did it wrong. But then again, I do not want to redirect to index, I want to redirect to the correct website according to the URL. And having a catch all means that for any 404 I would be redirecting to the index (which I don't want to do).

Another weird thing I found, is that whenever I type: https://www.fluento.net/privacy or https://www.fluento.net/tos I can reach those pages. This is the view that serves them:

```
<template>
  <iframe src="/tos.html"></iframe>
</template>
                                                                                                                                                                                      
<style scoped>                                                                                                                                                                        
object, iframe {                                                                                                                                                                      
  border: none;                                                                                                                                                                       
  height: 800px;                                                                                                                                                                      
  width: 100%;                                                                                                                                                                        
  min-height: calc(100vh - 125px);                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                     
</style>
```

Maybe not having any javascript makes those two routes work? Not sure, because the App component that calls them has some javascript already.

**EDIT:** For everyone in the same situation, I managed to find a fix. Not setting this as an answer because I don't really understand how this works, and can't explain it. But following this answer [Vue Router return 404 when revisit to the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399319/vue-router-return-404-when-revisit-to-the-url/58368467#58368467) in another question, this is how to implement this in Netlify:

At the end of the routes file in Vue, add this route to catch all the unknown routes and send them to an error page.

```
  {                                                                                                                                                                                   
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',                                                                                                                                                         
    name: 'error404',                                                                                                                                                                                      
    component: Error404                                                                                                                                                               
  }
```

The error page could be a view like this:

```
<template>
<p>Not found</p>
</template>
```

And then create a file in the folder that will be public after the build command is executed. In my case `npm run build` builds my project and adds the content of `public/` folder to the root of the website. So I added a file `public/_redirects` that will be added in the root of the website.

For example, if my website is https://mywebsite.com, there will be a https://mywebsite.com/_redirects file. This file is not accessible, but Netlify understands and will "compile".

`public/_redirects`:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

This is the part that I am not sure what it does, but please if someone could explain in the comments it would be great. But I think it redirects all the traffic from uncaught urls to the index with the original URL and then the index executes the vue-router.

This is it, if you look for an URL you don't catch in vue-router you should see the 404 page, otherwise you should see the correct view.

Comment: The reason it works **I think** is because vue-router only initialises and takes over when you hit /index.html (which is the same as /). So when you try and go to /about directly Netlify looks for about.html but obviously it doesn't find it. Vue-router however understands it but we need to go to /index.html first to initialise it and allow it to takeover routing. Soooo, why does `/*    /index.html   200` work then? What we are saying here is if anyone tries anything other than /index.html directly then send them to /index.html first to allow vue-router to be initialised.