# Catch-all route works in dev but not after build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I am writing an application where I would like all routes to [point to one component](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#Catch-all-404-Not-found-Route):

```
// router.ts

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import TimesView from './TimesView.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      // this one is just in case
      path: '/',
      name: 'times-home',
      component: TimesView
    },
    {
      path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
      name: 'times-anything-else',
      component: TimesView
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

```
// main.ts

import './tailwind.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

When running the app in `npm run dev` mode, a path such as `/%7B%22cities%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22` works fine (= the component `TimesView` is displayed).

After a `npm run build` and staring a web server such as `python -m http.server -d .\dist\` I get a 404 in the logs of the router

```
::1 - - [12/Oct/2023 13:01:22] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [12/Oct/2023 13:02:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [12/Oct/2023 13:02:28] "GET /assets/index-d3ddf5cb.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [12/Oct/2023 13:02:28] "GET /assets/index-1a9318c1.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
::1 - - [12/Oct/2023 13:02:39] code 404, message File not found
::1 - - [12/Oct/2023 13:02:39] "GET /%7B%22cities%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22UTC%22%2C%22timezone%22%3A%22Etc%2FUTC%22%7D%5D%2C%22defaultCity%22%3A%22UTC%22%2C%22dayStartHour%22%3A9%2C%22dayEndHour%22%3A18%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Browser-wise, I get the following 404 message:

```
Error response
Error code: 404

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 - Nothing matches the given URI.
```

Accessing `/` works fine.

What can be the reason for this catch-all not working?

Comment: You need to configure a webserver for SPA. SPAs expect that any 404 responds with index.html.  It's irrelevant to vue itself

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36399319/3001761 - this is a basic misunderstanding of how SPAs work. Not sure how to make `http.server` redirect, I certainly don't think there's a command line option for it, but e.g. [`serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) has a `-s`/`--single` flag.

Comment: @EstusFlask - thanks, I should have known better. I added a duplicate per Jon's pointer

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, and as I said above - I should have known better. I marked it as a duplicate of the post you mentioned.